# Expected number of tosses to get first head

Tags: probability

How to solve the problem of expected number of tosses to get first head using markov chains?

I'm not able to figure out how to write the transition matrix for this case.

Edit:

$$Transition \space matrix = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
1/2 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Expected number of steps to reach absorption state:

starting from heads $t_h = 1$

starting from tails $t_t = 1/2*t_t + 1/2* t_h$

$t_t$ = 1

Total steps = $t_t + t_h = 2$

Comment: you dont even need markov chains.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I want to use markov chains for this. Since this is a simple problem I thought this would help me understand how to use markov chains.

Comment: Please provide more context by adding some of your own works on this question (in your post, not in the comment). From the current version of the question, it is not clear to us what your level of background knowledge is. For example how much do you know about Markov chains.

Comment: I've added my attempt at writing a transition matrix for this problem. Now I'm trying to figure how to calculate expected number of steps taken to reach absorption state.

Comment: I've updated the question with my attempt at calculating expected number of steps to reach absorption state. Can someone tell me if its correct approach or not? .

Answer (score 0):

First identify your states.  Heads and tails.  Then, since you are waiting for your first head, start out with the vector $(0,1)$ for $100$% tails, so to speak.  Then find the probability of switching to heads, or staying tails, given that it is currently heads.

So the vector $(0,1)$ needs to turn into $(1/2, 1/2)$, making that the second column of the transition matrix.  Likewise the first column.

So iterating would give the overall probability of heads at any number of tosses, but would not guarantee that it was the first time heads came up.

I don't see how to get from there to expected value for the number, but hopefully that will get you started.

**EDIT**. Alternative description of the states: "got heads" vs. "never got heads."  So once you transition to "got heads" you can't transition back.  So the second column in this case would still be $(1/2,1/2)$ but the first column would have to be $(1,0)$.

Comment: The two states are $0:$no head has turned up yet, and $1:$ a head has appeared.  The transition probability from state $0$ to state $1$ is $1/2$, and the transition probability from state $1$ to state $1$ is $1$.   This is an [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain)

Comment: @saulspatz Just figured that out and edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the first head on the nth toss you must get a tail on each of the first n-1 tosses which has probability (1/2)^(n-1) and then get a head on the nth toss which has probability 1/2.  So the probability of getting the first head on the nth toss is (1/2)^n.  The expected value is 1(1/2)+ 2(1/2)^2+ 3(1/2)^3+ ...+ n(1/2)^n.

To get that, consider the general geometric sum:Y(r)= 1+ r+ r^2+ ...+ r^n= (1- r^(n+1))/(1- r).  Y'= 1+ 2r+ 3r^2+ ...+ nr^(n-1).
Multiply that by  r: rY'= r+ 2r^2+ 3r^3+ ...+ nr^n.